# How to find the text for a given returnKeyType?

Tags: uitextfield, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype, uikeyinput

Here is a question concerning the UITextInputTraits protocol.

In the documentation, section Managing the Keyboard Behavior, one can see the property: returnKeyType.

It takes its possible values from this:

```
typedef enum {
   UIReturnKeyDefault,
   UIReturnKeyGo,
   UIReturnKeyGoogle,
   UIReturnKeyJoin,
   UIReturnKeyNext,
   UIReturnKeyRoute,
   UIReturnKeySearch,
   UIReturnKeySend,
   UIReturnKeyYahoo,
   UIReturnKeyDone,
   UIReturnKeyEmergencyCall,
} UIReturnKeyType;
```

What I want is a way to get the matching text for a given value of the property returnKeyType.

For example, in English:

- if the value is UIReturnKeyDefault the text is “return”;
- if the value is UIReturnKeySearch the text is “Search”;
- … etc …

But when the language setting is different the text will be different.
I need a way to find out the appropriate text, whatever the value of the property returnKeyType is and whatever the language setting of the user is.

Thank you in advance for any relevant tip.

Comment: Did you ever find anything out?